# Visual Studio 2010 formatting after saving

Tags: visual-studio-2010, formatting

Visual Studio 2010 is giving me grief. When I make changes to an aspx file and save the formatted code changes from this:

[image]

to this... every time.

[image]

Here's my formatting.

[image]

In Tag Specific Options under HTML the P tag was missing. So I added this but this didn't fix the problem.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

to format a section: ctrl + k, ctrl + f or ctrl + e, ctrl + f

to format a document ctrl + e, ctrl + d